# change email content for new user in wordpress

Tags: email, wordpress

I need to change the default email text that will be sent while creating a new user in wordpress.

Where can i find the option to change the default text:

> Welcome [username] to [blogname]
>   Please find below your login details:
>   Username: [username]
>   Password: [password]
>   [blog url]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a couple of plugins that make this easy:

1. [SB Welcome Email Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/welcome-email-editor/)

Comment: Also I found that we can change the email message in the function wp_new_user_notification under wp-includes/pluggable.php. which avoids the use of the plugin

Comment: But that would also mean a WordPress update will break your code. It's better to use a plugin rather than edit WordPress core files.

Comment: You can hook into that function, and use it without editing the file.....thats how plugins like the ones above do it.

Comment: New User Email Setup link is broken. SB Welcome Email Editor worked like a charm.